# (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator

Tags: linux, debian, apache2

I recently upgrade my Debian server from Debian 10 (Buster) to Debian 11 (Bullseye).

Apache2 was upgrade to the 2.4.52-1~deb11u2 version.

Since that, I can't start Apache2...

I got the error:

```
(38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
```

I reinstalled apache2, but got the same error.

I also tried [How to fix '(38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator' after upgrading Apache from 2.4.18 to 2.4.46?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617147/how-to-fix-38function-not-implemented-ah00141-could-not-initialize-random-n) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your kernel.

After spinning up a new server in a cloud I have naturally upgraded all dependencies including the kernel before installing new ones. But I forgot to reboot the instance so it was still running on its default kernel from 2016.

After reboot everything resumed to work normally.

[This thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/l32x8p66g83pock2z4jwp46cmm8tg26h) pointed me to the right way.