# running apache on android with userland and ubuntu

Tags: apache, userland

Trying to setup apache http server on ubuntu on userland in android.

When i try to start apache service:

```
server_root@localhost:~$ sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                  
 * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 99: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
Setting ulimit failed. See README.Debian for more information.
[Mon Jan 22 08:30:34.566111 2024] [:crit] [pid 17770] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Unfortunately updating [kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71255831/38function-not-implemented-ah00141-could-not-initialize-random-number-genera) is not working in userland env.

Comment: For the folks searching for same answer.
I am using a simple python http server for now, till i find a solution:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32200