# Can't start Apache : Error : Could not initialize random number generator

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

My apache server doesn't start, here are my logs

```
nov. 01 20:34:46 ns3013535.ip-149-202-76.eu systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
nov. 01 20:34:46 ns3013535.ip-149-202-76.eu apachectl[1333176]: [Tue Nov 01 20:34:46.704027 2022] [:crit] [pid 1333176] (38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
nov. 01 20:34:46 ns3013535.ip-149-202-76.eu apachectl[1333173]: Action 'start' failed.
nov. 01 20:34:46 ns3013535.ip-149-202-76.eu apachectl[1333173]: The Apache error log may have more information.
nov. 01 20:34:46 ns3013535.ip-149-202-76.eu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nov. 01 20:34:46 ns3013535.ip-149-202-76.eu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nov. 01 20:34:46 ns3013535.ip-149-202-76.eu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

i'm on ubuntu 22.04LTS

kernel version 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64

apache2 version: 2.4.52
libapr1 version: 1.7.0-8

i updated all my package but nothing change
i already followed this thread too : [How to fix '(38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator' after upgrading Apache from 2.4.18 to 2.4.46?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617147/how-to-fix-38function-not-implemented-ah00141-could-not-initialize-random-n)